# Why this array creates a new object in the array than editing the existing one?

Tags: arrays, swiftui

The following code `appends` two new array objects in the format of `Row` struct. It has the data values of `10 and 10`
Then by clicking the `edit button` I'm editing only the `lineEndPos` data in the first array object at the `index 0` and editing the data value `10` to `77`.

The problem is when I insert, it always creates a new array object and adds to the array. I just want it to edit the existing data at the `index 0` and only the data in `lineEndPos`. Not to add a brand new item in the array.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Row: Identifiable {
    @State var id = 0
    @State var lineBeginPos: CGFloat = CGFloat (0)
    @State var lineEndPos: CGFloat = CGFloat (0)
  
 }

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var txt: String = ""
    @State var rows: [Row] = []

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text (txt.description)
            Button ("New append"){
                

                rows.append(Row(id: 0,lineBeginPos: CGFloat(10), lineEndPos: CGFloat(10) ))
                rows.append(Row(id: 1,lineBeginPos: CGFloat(10), lineEndPos: CGFloat(10) ))
               
            }
            
            Button ("Edit/insert at index 0"){
                rows.insert(Row(lineEndPos: CGFloat(77)), at: 0)
            }
            
            Button ("Print array"){
                print ("array" + rows.description)
                txt = "array" + rows.description
                              
            }
            
            Button ("remove all"){
                
                rows.removeAll()
                              
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, do not use `@State` in `struct Row`,  `@State` is **only** for use in a `View`. You need to read the basics of SwiftUI, see for example: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  and also read the basics of Swift, such as:  https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach, using the `rows` index to `edit` that particular `row` property.
Note, do not use `@State` in `struct Row`, `@State` is only for use in a `View`.

```
// -- here
struct Row: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var lineBeginPos: CGFloat
    var lineEndPos: CGFloat
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var txt: String = ""
    @State var rows: [Row] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // -- here
            List(rows) { row in
                Text ("\(row.lineEndPos)")
            }
            Text (txt.description)
            Button ("New append"){
                rows.append(Row(id: 0,lineBeginPos: CGFloat(10), lineEndPos: CGFloat(10) ))
                rows.append(Row(id: 1,lineBeginPos: CGFloat(10), lineEndPos: CGFloat(10) ))
            }
            Button ("Edit/insert at index 0"){
                if rows.count > 0 {
                    rows[0].lineEndPos = 77  // <-- here
                }
            }
            Button ("Print array"){
                print ("array" + rows.description)
                txt = "array" + rows.description
            }
            Button ("remove all"){
                rows.removeAll()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works. Do you have any recommendations of a book that I can learn these things? Everywhere on internet I see `insert` as the editing method, but it doesn't work. Your method works.

Comment: There are many `Swift` and `SwiftUI` books where you can learn the basics. A quick search should give you plenty to choose from.
 There are also a lot of info online, eg the links I mentioned in my comment.
There is also the `Swift` language documentation at: https://www.swift.org/documentation/
 and specifically the `collection` chapter with `array` info at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/collectiontypes/
 
It shows you how to use array, how to access the elements, etc... Remember there are two things here, the `Swift` and the `SwiftUI`.